# Laravel 5.1 AuthController user registration unique random id

Tags: laravel, registration

So i am having some issues with generating an unique fully random customerid.

Everything i try keeps giving me an blank column at the customer id spot in my database. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong!

Thanks in advance here is my code :

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => 'required|max:255|unique:gebruikers',
            'email' => 'required|max:255|unique:gebruikers',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            'customerid' => 'unique:gebruikers'
        ]);
    }
```

And

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'customerid' => str_random(30),
    ]);
}
```

and the register.blade.php :

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/register">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="customerid">
        Name
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
    </div>
    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>
    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        Confirm Password
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Mass assignment is not a good idea on creating a model by gathering data from user!

Comment: already changed it back to => haha but thanks.. still didn't fixed it btw. Do you know any solutions?

Comment: Do you have a `customerid` field in your `gebruikers` table?

Comment: Yes i have it haha already thought of that..

Comment: and what is its type?

Comment: the type is : varchar(255) @revo

Comment: did you mention customer id fillable in your model?

Comment: Wait going to check that out now!

Comment: Yes, but not in building your schema. By doing a mass assignment you have to define assigned fields as `fillable` from within your model.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel Worked Thanks! so now i got it fixed i am going to change it to a random number =P just heard it has to be a number instead of a string.. hope it works the same way!

Comment: @StefanoGroenland i wrote this answer,please accept this answer,it will helpful for others who are facing same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong operator '==', replace it to '=>'

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'customerid' => str_random(30),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: i don't know if it has to be an input aswell on the registration form? but i don't want that users can decide this just like asigning an id to an user upon registration.

Answer (score 0):

did you mention customer id fillable in your model? – Imtiaz Pabel

Worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make this field fillable in your model

```
protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'customerid'];
```